# Regex to filter only unmatching string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to make a regex for a mylyn task repo connector to select only issues that *do not* have the label with the string `needs info`

I'm afraid I have zero experience with regex, so have tried each of the following with equally zero results:

```
(^needs info)    <- filters for only *has* needs info label
^(needs info)    <- filters for only *has* needs info label
(?!needs info)   <- does nothing
^(?!needs info)  <- does nothing
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Closing this as it looks like its the mylyn connector Im trying to use it with is to dumb to properly allow full regex's :\

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like the issue is software error rather than code so there is no possible SO solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `.*` inside the negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*\bneeds info\b).+
```

The above regex would match all the lines which don't have the string `needs info`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vP4gL5/3)

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with that one as it still operates as if there is not filter. Although my attempts were probably laughable, Im beginning to think it may be down to the mylyn connector I am using rather than the regex used...

Comment: it works in the demo site. Which lang are you running?

Comment: It probably is in Java (eclipse based plugin) but I just enter the regex into a form field that asks for a label regex, so really no telling how it's actually used. I see that it does indeed work great on the demo though, thanks!

Comment: in java, you need to escape the backslash one more time. `pattern.compile("^(?!.*\\bneeds info\\b).+");`